# Logging WCF message sizes

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, message

I am using WCF to send some Linq objects across the wire. I want to log message size either using Message logging or tracing. I don't however want, or have the ability to use the config file to set this up. I am struggling to figure out how to do this programatically. I don't care if this happens at the host of client. I control both.

Does anyone have experience doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marc's right, Message Inspectors will allow you to do this. Create a class that: Implements [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx). The below method will be made available where you can implement code to manipulate the request message.

```
Public Function AfterReceiveRequest(ByRef request As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, ByVal channel As System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel, ByVal instanceContext As System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext) As Object Implements System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest
    'Output the request message to immediate window
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*** SERVER - RECEIVED REQUEST ***")
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(request.ToString())

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Also, the following [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) may also provide some help.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Not programming, but perhaps: [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

Alternatively, look into [message inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx). I don't have a specific example for size logging, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Fiddler, which can log your HTTP messages if your using one of the wsHttp or basicHttp bindings. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/