# WCF error: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException the maximum message size quota for incoming messages has been exceeded

Tags: c#, wcf

We are seeing this error related to an http file transfer request

> WCF error, System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException the maximum message size quota for incoming messages has been exceeded.

I've seen several posts related to this message, with the general response of just bump it to the max.

What if you want to force a limit on the file transfer size. We want to allow the user to only transfer files 60MB (62914560) and smaller.

Which setting should be set to 62914560? `maxStringContentLength` or `maxArrayLength`?

Is there overhead for the envelope around the request? In other words, will the max allowed download file size be 60MB? Or is it smaller, file size + request overhead <= 60MB?

If it is the latter, can this be determined. Is the overhead fixed size? Or is the overhead a function of other settings (eg `maxBytesPerRead`)?

Does SSL impact the file (overall message) size? How much?

I'm trying to understand exactly how it works. Changing the size seems arbitrary. How do I know what the correct setting value is to allow downloads of files that are only 60MB or less. One of the things I am seeing is that a zip file of 53776931 bytes will throw the exception. Prior to the download, I'm checking the size of the file and it is clearly less than 60MB. What is causing the message to exceed the maximum message size?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify readersQuota in both your client and server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable logging and see how big your message really is - it's the only way I could solve it when I had a similiar issue [Logging WCF message sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899741/logging-wcf-message-sizes)

Don't be tempted to crank the maxmessagesize up to the max value, it can drain your application of memory if it really does try to return a message that big.